# PHPStorm 9 + XAMPP + xdebug, debugger not working

Tags: php, xampp, phpstorm, xdebug

Despite following all the tutorials step by step, breakpoints and php debugging do not work.

Heres my set up:

PHPStorm 9.0.2, server In place 'C:/Users/hedge/Dev/PHPStorm/gpstudios/dist'

XAMPP with xdebug 2.3.3-5.6-vc11

php.ini:

```
[XDebug]
zend_extension = "C:\Dev\XAMPP\php\ext\php_xdebug-2.3.3-5.6-vc11.dll"
xdebug.remote_enable = 1
xdebug.remote_host = 127.0.0.1
xdebug.remote_connect_back = 1
xdebug.remote_port = 9000
xdebug.idekey = "PHPSTORM"
xdebug.profiler_enable = 1
xdebug.remote_log = "C:\Dev\XAMPP\tmp\xdebug.log"
```

httpd-vhosts.conf:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    DocumentRoot "C:/Users/hedge/Dev/PHPStorm/gpstudios/dist"       
    ServerName local.gpstudios

    <Directory "C:/Users/hedge/Dev/PHPStorm/gpstudios/dist">        
        Header set Cache-Control "max-age=0, private, no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate"      
        Header set Pragma "no-cache"        
        Header set Expires "Wed, 11 Jan 1984 05:00:00 GMT"      
        Options Indexes FollowSymLinks Includes ExecCGI     
        AllowOverride All       
        Require all granted     
    </Directory>        
</VirtualHost>
```

hosts:

```
127.0.0.1           local.gpstudios
```

Jetbrains IDE support (Chrome):

[image]

In phpstorm when I run 'web server debug validate' in phpstorm:

[image]

I've tried setting xdebug.remote_host to 'local.gpstudios', still doesn't help.

I run phpstorm in debug mode and enable 'listen for php debug connections' 
'C:\Dev\XAMPP\tmp\xdebug.log' never gets created.

If I add the line 'xdebug.remote_autostart = 1' to php.ini, php debugging works!!! but when I use phpmyadmin it runs so slowly I don't want to consider using this workaround.
I've tried everything, looked at loads of similar stackoverflow questions. Nothing. Flipping. Works.

Please help, I know there's a quick workaround but it really makes phpmyadmin terribly slow. I shouldn't have to set remote_autostart... Really tearing my hair out over this.

Comment: check my answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/70778833/9277453 about debug enabling

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Without the `xdebug.remote_autostart = 1` option, you have to enable xdebug for every domain. You can do this by adding a new bookmark to the site you want to debug.

As helper tools, I can recommend the following:

- https://www.jetbrains.com/phpstorm/marklets/ - Cross browser bookmarklet, just drag&drop it to your bookmark bar and press Start debugger if you want to enable it.
- https://addons.mozilla.org/hu/firefox/addon/the-easiest-xdebug/ - For firefox
- https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/xdebug-helper/eadndfjplgieldjbigjakmdgkmoaaaoc - For chrome

Comment: The bookmarklets and the chrome extension worked... but shouldnt the jetbrains ide support addon do this automatically when I debug it in phpstorm? Most tutorials don't bother mentioning the bookmarklets anymore, I assumed it was an outdated method. I'm sure there's another way.

Comment: That extension says that it is for debugging HTML/CSS/Javascript. Furthermore, it can be used with other IDEs also, like PyCharm and Rubymine. I don't think that it has any connection with PHP specifically.

Comment: ok. So I had another look at the tutorials and it does indeed mention the above chrome addon. Still, the documentation is rubbish.

Comment: @hedgehog90 Quite possibly. Although I have not found any serious issues with reading their docs and making it work (possibly because it's not so different to other IDEs/text editors that I have used to debug in the past...)