# PhpStorm & XAMPP - debugging not starting

Tags: php, debugging, phpstorm

I am having a hard time with PhpStorm debugger. I read all their documentation and I have setup debug properly (according to both `phpinfo()`, debug tailored installation report and PhpStorm analysis).

However, no matter what I try, the debugger wont trigger.

My setup is the following:

I changed XAMPP document root to: `c:\src\project\www`

My project has the following structure:

```
project    
 | www (used by XAMPP to serve the website)
 | src    
   | --theme (symlinked to wp-content/themes)    
   | --plugins (symlinked to wp-content/plugins)
```

and apparently, this setup works as all my plugins and theme are correctly working and displayed on the screen.

When I then start to run the debugger, it simply won't trigger.

This is the setup for the debugger on PhpStorm:

**Server:**

```
Host: localhost
Port: 80
Debugger: xdebug
```

**Mappings** (where I think there's something off)

```
src/theme   --> c:/src/project/www/wp-content/theme/
src/plugins --> c:/src/project/www/wp-content/plugins/
```

but nothing happens. No mappings errors, no debug, nothing at all.

Can you please explain to me what am I doing wrong here?

let me know if you need more info.

**EDIT:**

php.ini added line for debug (from xdebug website):

```
zend_extension = C:\xampp\php\ext\php_xdebug-2.5.4-7.1-vc14.dll
```

PhpStorm PHP settings:

[image]

Comment: what do you mean `start the debugger` ?  be specific, and show how you setup xdebug both in your php.ini files and in phpstorm.

Comment: please check the updated question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is from my setup :

**php.ini**

```
[xdebug]
;zend_extension=xdebug.so
zend_extension=/usr/local/Cellar/php55-xdebug/2.4.0/xdebug.so
xdebug.remote_enable=1
xdebug.remote_connect_back=0
xdebug.remote_handler=dbgp
xdebug.remote_host=localhost
xdebug.remote_port=9002
xdebug.remote_log="/mnt/log/xdebug.log"
xdebug.remote_autostart=1
xdebug.idekey=phpstorm
xdebug.remote_mode = req
```

**phpstorm :**

setup in accordance with above parameters.  Note that I use port 9002 to skit around a conflict with `php-fpm` which is part of my stack. Also, i force xdebug logging on a specific drive to ease the burden on my laptop SSD, etc ... Adapt to your configuration.

[image]

Comment: I needed to adjust the php.ini file. Now it's debugging properly. Thanks. I just don't understand why xdebug doesn't provide the full code to add to php.ini file, but anyway, it's working now, which is the important thing here

Comment: Yes, this helps. Don't forget if using php storm to turn off break at first lines in php option , i was stuck and wondering is my app not loading, then i realized it is stuck on breakpoint in IDE (PhpStorm)

Answer (score 0):

No one says but you may need to add to xampp/xamppfiles/etc/php.ini:

`xdebug.mode=debug,develop`

together with server setup:

[image: xdebug setup in intellij]