# Trouble using Xdebug in PhpStorm combined with WSL and Lighttpd

Tags: php, phpstorm, windows-subsystem-for-linux, lighttpd

#### Problem:

I cannot get Xdebug to pick-up or "hear" debug connections from my PHP code which is hosted locally through Lighttpd in the Windows subsystem.

#### Attempts:

I have tried to configure it traditionally (i.e via the documentation)

I have tried and SSH tunnel from Windows to Linux (Ubuntu) and setting up the debugger CLI from that as well.

I have also tried explicitly determining the debug channel by passing a cookie/header.

I have also tried using the Chrome extension via my index.php file

---

php.ini on Windows

```
zend_extension = C:\php\ext\php_xdebug-2.7.2-7.1-vc14-nts.dll
xdebug.remote_autostart = 1
xdebug.profiler_append = 0
xdebug.profiler_enable = 0
xdebug.profiler_enable_trigger = 0
xdebug.profiler_output_dir = "c:\xampp\tmp"
;xdebug.profiler_output_name = "cachegrind.out.%t-%s"
xdebug.remote_enable = 1
xdebug.remote_handler = "dbgp"
xdebug.remote_host = "127.0.0.1"
xdebug.remote_log = "c:\xampp\tmp\xdebug.txt"
xdebug.remote_port = 9000
xdebug.trace_output_dir = "c:\xampp\tmp"
;36000 = 10h
xdebug.remote_cookie_expire_time = 36000
```

---

php.ini on WSL

```
xdebug.remote_autostart = 1 
xdebug.profiler_append = 0   
xdebug.profiler_enable = 0  
xdebug.profiler_enable_trigger = 0   
xdebug.profiler_output_dir = "c:\xampp\tmp"
;xdebug.profiler_output_name = "cachegrind.out.%t-%s"   
xdebug.remote_enable = 1           
xdebug.remote_handler = "dbgp"   
xdebug.remote_host = "127.0.0.1"    
xdebug.remote_log = "c:\xampp\tmp\xdebug.txt"  
xdebug.remote_port = 9000          
xdebug.trace_output_dir = "c:\xampp\tmp"    
;36000 = 10h                
xdebug.remote_cookie_expire_time = 36000
```

---

#### While setting up:

The Windows setup took forever and a lot of bending over backward to locate everything.

The SSH tunnel to WSL configuration pretty much set up and auto-detected everything.

My Lighttpd is pointing to the localhost and then running my index.php for my various projects.

My hostfile overrides the localhost to be something like `<projectname>.localhost/<myroute>`

---

#### Question:

I want to be able to use breakpoints in PhpStorm with this (local) environment if possible, maybe I am going about this wrong or maybe I completely reconfigured this incorrectly.  Any help would be appreciated.

#### PHPInfo():

```
PHP API => 20180731
PHP Extension => 20180731
Zend Extension => 320180731
Zend Extension Build => API320180731,NTS
PHP Extension Build => API20180731,NTS
Debug Build => no
Thread Safety => disabled
Zend Signal Handling => enabled
Zend Memory Manager => enabled
Zend Multibyte Support => provided by mbstring
IPv6 Support => enabled
DTrace Support => disabled

Registered PHP Streams => https, ftps, compress.zlib, compress.bzip2, php, file, glob, data, http, ftp, phar, zip
Registered Stream Socket Transports => tcp, udp, unix, udg, ssl, tls, tlsv1.0, tlsv1.1, tlsv1.2
Registered Stream Filters => zlib.*, bzip2.*, convert.iconv.*, string.rot13, string.toupper, string.tolower, string.strip_tags, convert.*, consumed, dechunk

This program makes use of the Zend Scripting Language Engine:
Zend Engine v3.3.5, Copyright (c) 1998-2018 Zend Technologies
    with Zend OPcache v7.3.5, Copyright (c) 1999-2018, by Zend Technologies


 _______________________________________________________________________


Configuration

bcmath

BCMath support => enabled

Directive => Local Value => Master Value
bcmath.scale => 0 => 0

bz2

BZip2 Support => Enabled
Stream Wrapper support => compress.bzip2://
Stream Filter support => bzip2.decompress, bzip2.compress
BZip2 Version => 1.0.6, 6-Sept-2010

calendar

Calendar support => enabled

Core

PHP Version => 7.3.5

Directive => Local Value => Master Value
allow_url_fopen => On => On
allow_url_include => Off => Off
arg_separator.input => & => &
arg_separator.output => & => &
auto_append_file => no value => no value
auto_globals_jit => On => On
auto_prepend_file => no value => no value
browscap => no value => no value
default_charset => UTF-8 => UTF-8
default_mimetype => text/html => text/html
disable_classes => no value => no value
disable_functions => no value => no value
display_errors => STDOUT => STDOUT
display_startup_errors => On => On
doc_root => no value => no value
docref_ext => no value => no value
docref_root => no value => no value
enable_dl => Off => Off
enable_post_data_reading => On => On
error_append_string => no value => no value
error_log => no value => no value
error_prepend_string => no value => no value
error_reporting => 32767 => 32767
expose_php => On => On
extension_dir => /home/linuxbrew/.linuxbrew/lib/php/pecl/20180731 => /home/linuxbrew/.linuxbrew/lib/php/pecl/20180731
file_uploads => On => On
hard_timeout => 2 => 2
highlight.comment => <font style="color: #FF8000">#FF8000</font> => <font style="color: #FF8000">#FF8000</font>
highlight.default => <font style="color: #0000BB">#0000BB</font> => <font style="color: #0000BB">#0000BB</font>
highlight.html => <font style="color: #000000">#000000</font> => <font style="color: #000000">#000000</font>
highlight.keyword => <font style="color: #007700">#007700</font> => <font style="color: #007700">#007700</font>
highlight.string => <font style="color: #DD0000">#DD0000</font> => <font style="color: #DD0000">#DD0000</font>
html_errors => Off => Off
ignore_repeated_errors => Off => Off
ignore_repeated_source => Off => Off
ignore_user_abort => Off => Off
implicit_flush => On => On
include_path => .:/home/linuxbrew/.linuxbrew/Cellar/php/7.3.5/share/php/pear => .:/home/linuxbrew/.linuxbrew/Cellar/php/7.3.5/share/php/pear
input_encoding => no value => no value
internal_encoding => no value => no value
log_errors => On => On
log_errors_max_len => 1024 => 1024
mail.add_x_header => Off => Off
mail.force_extra_parameters => no value => no value
mail.log => no value => no value
max_execution_time => 0 => 0
max_file_uploads => 20 => 20
max_input_nesting_level => 64 => 64
max_input_time => -1 => -1
max_input_vars => 1000 => 1000
memory_limit => 128M => 128M
open_basedir => no value => no value
output_buffering => 0 => 0
output_encoding => no value => no value
output_handler => no value => no value
post_max_size => 8M => 8M
precision => 14 => 14
realpath_cache_size => 4096K => 4096K
realpath_cache_ttl => 120 => 120
register_argc_argv => On => On
report_memleaks => On => On
report_zend_debug => Off => Off
request_order => GP => GP
sendmail_from => no value => no value
sendmail_path =>  -t -i  =>  -t -i
serialize_precision => -1 => -1
short_open_tag => Off => Off
SMTP => localhost => localhost
smtp_port => 25 => 25
sys_temp_dir => no value => no value
syslog.facility => LOG_USER => LOG_USER
syslog.filter => no-ctrl => no-ctrl
syslog.ident => php => php
track_errors => Off => Off
unserialize_callback_func => no value => no value
upload_max_filesize => 2M => 2M
upload_tmp_dir => no value => no value
user_dir => no value => no value
user_ini.cache_ttl => 300 => 300
user_ini.filename => .user.ini => .user.ini
variables_order => GPCS => GPCS
xmlrpc_error_number => 0 => 0
xmlrpc_errors => Off => Off
zend.assertions => 1 => 1
zend.detect_unicode => On => On
zend.enable_gc => On => On
zend.multibyte => Off => Off
zend.script_encoding => no value => no value
zend.signal_check => Off => Off

ctype

ctype functions => enabled

curl

Phar

Phar: PHP Archive support => enabled
Phar API version => 1.1.1
Phar-based phar archives => enabled
Tar-based phar archives => enabled
ZIP-based phar archives => enabled
gzip compression => enabled
bzip2 compression => enabled
OpenSSL support => enabled


Phar based on pear/PHP_Archive, original concept by Davey Shafik.
Phar fully realized by Gregory Beaver and Marcus Boerger.
Portions of tar implementation Copyright (c) 2003-2009 Tim Kientzle.
Directive => Local Value => Master Value
phar.cache_list => no value => no value
phar.readonly => On => On
phar.require_hash => On => On

phpdbg_webhelper

Version => 0.5.0

Directive => Local Value => Master Value
phpdbg.auth => no value => no value
phpdbg.path => no value => no value

posix

POSIX support => enabled

pspell

PSpell Support => enabled

readline

Readline Support => enabled
Readline library => EditLine wrapper

Directive => Local Value => Master Value
cli.pager => no value => no value
cli.prompt => \b \>  => \b \>

Reflection

Reflection => enabled

session

Session Support => enabled
Registered save handlers => files user
Registered serializer handlers => php_serialize php php_binary wddx

Directive => Local Value => Master Value
session.auto_start => Off => Off
session.cache_expire => 180 => 180
session.cache_limiter => nocache => nocache
session.cookie_domain => no value => no value
session.cookie_httponly => no value => no value
session.cookie_lifetime => 0 => 0
session.cookie_path => / => /
session.cookie_samesite => no value => no value
session.cookie_secure => 0 => 0
session.gc_divisor => 1000 => 1000
session.gc_maxlifetime => 1440 => 1440
session.gc_probability => 1 => 1
session.lazy_write => On => On
session.name => PHPSESSID => PHPSESSID
session.referer_check => no value => no value
session.save_handler => files => files
session.save_path => no value => no value
session.serialize_handler => php => php
session.sid_bits_per_character => 5 => 5
session.sid_length => 26 => 26
session.upload_progress.cleanup => On => On
session.upload_progress.enabled => On => On
session.upload_progress.freq => 1% => 1%
session.upload_progress.min_freq => 1 => 1
session.upload_progress.name => PHP_SESSION_UPLOAD_PROGRESS => PHP_SESSION_UPLOAD_PROGRESS
session.upload_progress.prefix => upload_progress_ => upload_progress_
session.use_cookies => 1 => 1
session.use_only_cookies => 1 => 1
session.use_strict_mode => 0 => 0
session.use_trans_sid => 0 => 0
sqlite3

SQLite3 support => enabled
SQLite Library => 3.28.0

Directive => Local Value => Master Value
sqlite3.defensive => 1 => 1
sqlite3.extension_dir => no value => no value

standard

Dynamic Library Support => enabled
Path to sendmail =>  -t -i

Directive => Local Value => Master Value
assert.active => 1 => 1
assert.bail => 0 => 0
assert.callback => no value => no value
assert.exception => 0 => 0
assert.quiet_eval => 0 => 0
assert.warning => 1 => 1
auto_detect_line_endings => 0 => 0
default_socket_timeout => 60 => 60
from => no value => no value
session.trans_sid_hosts => no value => no value
session.trans_sid_tags => a=href,area=href,frame=src,form= => a=href,area=href,frame=src,form=
url_rewriter.hosts => no value => no value
url_rewriter.tags => form= => form=
user_agent => no value => no value

sysvmsg

sysvmsg support => enabled

sysvsem

sysvsem support => enabled

sysvshm

sysvshm support => enabled

tidy

Tidy support => enabled
libTidy Version => 5.6.0
libTidy Release => 2017/11/25

Directive => Local Value => Master Value
tidy.clean_output => no value => no value
tidy.default_config => no value => no value

tokenizer

Tokenizer Support => enabled

wddx

WDDX Support => enabled
WDDX Session Serializer => enabled

xml

XML Support => active
XML Namespace Support => active
libxml2 Version => 2.9.9

xmlreader

XMLReader => enabled

xmlrpc

core library version => xmlrpc-epi v. 0.51
author => Dan Libby
homepage => http://xmlrpc-epi.sourceforge.net
open sourced by => Epinions.com

xmlwriter

XMLWriter => enabled

xsl

XSL => enabled
libxslt Version => 1.1.33
libxslt compiled against libxml Version => 2.9.9
EXSLT => enabled
libexslt Version => 1.1.33

Zend OPcache

Opcode Caching => Disabled
Optimization => Disabled
SHM Cache => Enabled
File Cache => Disabled
Startup Failed => Opcode Caching is disabled for CLI

Directive => Local Value => Master Value
opcache.blacklist_filename => no value => no value
opcache.consistency_checks => 0 => 0
opcache.dups_fix => Off => Off
opcache.enable => On => On
opcache.enable_cli => Off => Off
opcache.enable_file_override => Off => Off
opcache.error_log => no value => no value
opcache.file_cache => no value => no value
opcache.file_cache_consistency_checks => 1 => 1
opcache.file_cache_only => 0 => 0
opcache.file_update_protection => 2 => 2
opcache.force_restart_timeout => 180 => 180
opcache.huge_code_pages => Off => Off
opcache.interned_strings_buffer => 8 => 8
opcache.lockfile_path => /tmp => /tmp
opcache.log_verbosity_level => 1 => 1
opcache.max_accelerated_files => 10000 => 10000
opcache.max_file_size => 0 => 0
opcache.max_wasted_percentage => 5 => 5
opcache.memory_consumption => 128 => 128
opcache.opt_debug_level => 0 => 0
opcache.optimization_level => 0x7FFEBFFF => 0x7FFEBFFF
opcache.preferred_memory_model => no value => no value
opcache.protect_memory => 0 => 0
opcache.restrict_api => no value => no value
opcache.revalidate_freq => 2 => 2
opcache.revalidate_path => Off => Off
opcache.save_comments => 1 => 1
opcache.use_cwd => On => On
opcache.validate_permission => Off => Off
opcache.validate_root => Off => Off
opcache.validate_timestamps => On => On

zip

Zip => enabled
Zip version => 1.15.4
Libzip headers version => 1.5.2
Libzip library version => 1.5.2

zlib

ZLib Support => enabled
Stream Wrapper => compress.zlib://
Stream Filter => zlib.inflate, zlib.deflate
Compiled Version => 1.2.11
Linked Version => 1.2.11

Directive => Local Value => Master Value
zlib.output_compression => Off => Off
zlib.output_compression_level => -1 => -1
zlib.output_handler => no value => no value

Additional Modules

Module Name

Environment

Variable => Value
MANPATH => /home/linuxbrew/.linuxbrew/share/man:
SHELL => /bin/bash
TERM => xterm-256color
HOMEBREW_REPOSITORY => /home/linuxbrew/.linuxbrew/Homebrew
WSLENV =>
COCOS_CONSOLE_ROOT => /mnt/c/Users/User/Desktop/cocos2d/cocos2d-x-3.16/tools/cocos2d-console/bin
USER => user
NAME => DESKTOP-COMPUTER0
COCOS_TEMPLATES_ROOT => /mnt/c/Users/User/Desktop/cocos2d/cocos2d-x-3.16/templates
LS_COLORS => rs=0:di=1;35:ln=01;36:mh=00:pi=40;33:so=01;35:do=01;35:bd=40;33;01:cd=40;33;01:or=40;31;01:su=37;41:sg=30;43:ca=30;41:tw=30;42:ow=34;42:st=37;44:ex=01;32:*.tar=01;31:*.tgz=01;31:*.arj=01;31:*.taz=01;31:*.lzh=01;31:*.lzma=01;31:*.tlz=01;31:*.txz=01;31:*.zip=01;31:*.z=01;31:*.Z=01;31:*.dz=01;31:*.gz=01;31:*.lz=01;31:*.xz=01;31:*.bz2=01;31:*.bz=01;31:*.tbz=01;31:*.tbz2=01;31:*.tz=01;31:*.deb=01;31:*.rpm=01;31:*.jar=01;31:*.war=01;31:*.ear=01;31:*.sar=01;31:*.rar=01;31:*.ace=01;31:*.zoo=01;31:*.cpio=01;31:*.7z=01;31:*.rz=01;31:*.jpg=01;35:*.jpeg=01;35:*.gif=01;35:*.bmp=01;35:*.pbm=01;35:*.pgm=01;35:*.ppm=01;35:*.tga=01;35:*.xbm=01;35:*.xpm=01;35:*.tif=01;35:*.tiff=01;35:*.png=01;35:*.svg=01;35:*.svgz=01;35:*.mng=01;35:*.pcx=01;35:*.mov=01;35:*.mpg=01;35:*.mpeg=01;35:*.m2v=01;35:*.mkv=01;35:*.webm=01;35:*.ogm=01;35:*.mp4=01;35:*.m4v=01;35:*.mp4v=01;35:*.vob=01;35:*.qt=01;35:*.nuv=01;35:*.wmv=01;35:*.asf=01;35:*.rm=01;35:*.rmvb=01;35:*.flc=01;35:*.avi=01;35:*.fli=01;35:*.flv=01;35:*.gl=01;35:*.dl=01;35:*.xcf=01;35:*.xwd=01;35:*.yuv=01;35:*.cgm=01;35:*.emf=01;35:*.axv=01;35:*.anx=01;35:*.ogv=01;35:*.ogx=01;35:*.aac=00;36:*.au=00;36:*.flac=00;36:*.mid=00;36:*.midi=00;36:*.mka=00;36:*.mp3=00;36:*.mpc=00;36:*.ogg=00;36:*.ra=00;36:*.wav=00;36:*.axa=00;36:*.oga=00;36:*.spx=00;36:*.xspf=00;36:
WSL_DISTRO_NAME => Legacy
HOSTTYPE => x86_64
PATH => /home/linuxbrew/.linuxbrew/bin:/home/linuxbrew/.linuxbrew/sbin:/mnt/c/Users/User/Desktop/cocos2d/cocos2d-x-3.16/templates:/mnt/c/Users/User/Desktop/cocos2d:/mnt/c/Users/User/Desktop/cocos2d/cocos2d-x-3.16/tools/cocos2d-console/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games:/mnt/c/Program Files (x86)/Common Files/Oracle/Java/javapath:/mnt/c/Program Files (x86)/Intel/iCLS Client/:/mnt/c/Program Files/Intel/iCLS Client/:/mnt/c/Windows/system32:/mnt/c/Windows:/mnt/c/Windows/System32/Wbem:/mnt/c/Windows/System32/WindowsPowerShell/v1.0/:/mnt/c/Program Files (x86)/NVIDIA Corporation/PhysX/Common:/mnt/c/Program Files (x86)/Intel/Intel(R) Management Engine Components/DAL:/mnt/c/Program Files/Intel/Intel(R) Management Engine Components/DAL:/mnt/c/Program Files (x86)/Intel/Intel(R) Management Engine Components/IPT:/mnt/c/Program Files/Intel/Intel(R) Management Engine Components/IPT:/mnt/c/php:/mnt/c/ProgramData/ComposerSetup/bin:/mnt/c/WINDOWS/system32:/mnt/c/WINDOWS:/mnt/c/WINDOWS/System32/Wbem:/mnt/c/WINDOWS/System32/WindowsPowerShell/v1.0/:/mnt/c/Program Files (x86)/Yarn/bin/:/mnt/c/WINDOWS/System32/OpenSSH/:/mnt/c/Python27:/mnt/c/Users/User/Desktop/phantomjs/bin:/mnt/c/Program Files (x86)/GtkSharp/2.12/bin:/mnt/c/Program Files/dotnet/:/mnt/c/Program Files/PuTTY/:/mnt/c/Program Files/Git/cmd:/mnt/c/Program Files/nodejs/C:/Program Files/Java/jdk-11.0.1/bin:/mnt/c/Program Files (x86)/Intel/iCLS Client/:/mnt/c/Program Files/Intel/iCLS Client/:/mnt/c/Windows/system32:/mnt/c/Windows:/mnt/c/Windows/System32/Wbem:/mnt/c/Windows/System32/WindowsPowerShell/v1.0/:/mnt/c/Program Files (x86)/NVIDIA Corporation/PhysX/Common:/mnt/c/Program Files (x86)/Intel/Intel(R) Management Engine Components/DAL:/mnt/c/Program Files/Intel/Intel(R) Management Engine Components/DAL:/mnt/c/Program Files (x86)/Intel/Intel(R) Management Engine Components/IPT:/mnt/c/Program Files/Intel/Intel(R) Management Engine Components/IPT:/mnt/c/php:/mnt/c/ProgramData/ComposerSetup/bin:/mnt/c/Program Files (x86)/Yarn/bin/:/mnt/c/Program Files/nodejs/:/mnt/c/Windows/System32/OpenSSH/:/mnt/c/Python27:/mnt/c/Users/User/Desktop/phantomjs/bin:/mnt/c/Program Files (x86)/Microsoft VS Code/bin:/mnt/c/Program Files (x86)/GtkSharp/2.12/bin:/mnt/c/Program Files/dotnet/:/mnt/c/Program Files/PuTTY/:/mnt/c/Program Files/Git/cmd:/mnt/c/Workspace/cocos2d-x-3.16/templates:/mnt/c/Workspace/cocos2d-x-3.16/tools/cocos2d-co:/mnt/c/Users/User/AppData/Local/Android/Sdk/platform-tools:/mnt/c/Users/User/AppData/Local/Microsoft/Wi:/mnt/c/Users/User/AppData/Local/Programs/Microsoft VS Code/bin:/mnt/c/Users/User/AppData/Local/hyper/app-2.0.0/resources/bin:/home/user/.composer/vendor/bin
PWD => /home/linuxbrew/.linuxbrew/etc/php/7.3
LANG => en_CA.UTF-8
PS1 => \[\033[38;5;13m\]\u\[\]\[\033[38;5;15m\] \[\]\[\033[38;5;225m\]\w\[\]\[\033[38;5;15m\] \[\]\[\033[38;5;5m\]\$\[\]
COCOS_X_ROOT => /mnt/c/Users/User/Desktop/cocos2d
SHLVL => 1
HOME => /home/user
HOMEBREW_PREFIX => /home/linuxbrew/.linuxbrew
LOGNAME => user
LESSOPEN => | /usr/bin/lesspipe %s
INFOPATH => /home/linuxbrew/.linuxbrew/share/info:
HOMEBREW_CELLAR => /home/linuxbrew/.linuxbrew/Cellar
LESSCLOSE => /usr/bin/lesspipe %s %s
_ => /home/linuxbrew/.linuxbrew/bin/php
OLDPWD => /home/linuxbrew/.linuxbrew/etc/php

PHP Variables

Variable => Value
$_SERVER['MANPATH'] => /home/linuxbrew/.linuxbrew/share/man:
$_SERVER['SHELL'] => /bin/bash
$_SERVER['TERM'] => xterm-256color
$_SERVER['HOMEBREW_REPOSITORY'] => /home/linuxbrew/.linuxbrew/Homebrew
$_SERVER['WSLENV'] =>
$_SERVER['COCOS_CONSOLE_ROOT'] => /mnt/c/Users/User/Desktop/cocos2d/cocos2d-x-3.16/tools/cocos2d-console/bin
$_SERVER['USER'] => user
$_SERVER['NAME'] => DESKTOP-COMPUTER0
$_SERVER['COCOS_TEMPLATES_ROOT'] => /mnt/c/Users/User/Desktop/cocos2d/cocos2d-x-3.16/templates
$_SERVER['LS_COLORS'] => rs=0:di=1;35:ln=01;36:mh=00:pi=40;33:so=01;35:do=01;35:bd=40;33;01:cd=40;33;01:or=40;31;01:su=37;41:sg=30;43:ca=30;41:tw=30;42:ow=34;42:st=37;44:ex=01;32:*.tar=01;31:*.tgz=01;31:*.arj=01;31:*.taz=01;31:*.lzh=01;31:*.lzma=01;31:*.tlz=01;31:*.txz=01;31:*.zip=01;31:*.z=01;31:*.Z=01;31:*.dz=01;31:*.gz=01;31:*.lz=01;31:*.xz=01;31:*.bz2=01;31:*.bz=01;31:*.tbz=01;31:*.tbz2=01;31:*.tz=01;31:*.deb=01;31:*.rpm=01;31:*.jar=01;31:*.war=01;31:*.ear=01;31:*.sar=01;31:*.rar=01;31:*.ace=01;31:*.zoo=01;31:*.cpio=01;31:*.7z=01;31:*.rz=01;31:*.jpg=01;35:*.jpeg=01;35:*.gif=01;35:*.bmp=01;35:*.pbm=01;35:*.pgm=01;35:*.ppm=01;35:*.tga=01;35:*.xbm=01;35:*.xpm=01;35:*.tif=01;35:*.tiff=01;35:*.png=01;35:*.svg=01;35:*.svgz=01;35:*.mng=01;35:*.pcx=01;35:*.mov=01;35:*.mpg=01;35:*.mpeg=01;35:*.m2v=01;35:*.mkv=01;35:*.webm=01;35:*.ogm=01;35:*.mp4=01;35:*.m4v=01;35:*.mp4v=01;35:*.vob=01;35:*.qt=01;35:*.nuv=01;35:*.wmv=01;35:*.asf=01;35:*.rm=01;35:*.rmvb=01;35:*.flc=01;35:*.avi=01;35:*.fli=01;35:*.flv=01;35:*.gl=01;35:*.dl=01;35:*.xcf=01;35:*.xwd=01;35:*.yuv=01;35:*.cgm=01;35:*.emf=01;35:*.axv=01;35:*.anx=01;35:*.ogv=01;35:*.ogx=01;35:*.aac=00;36:*.au=00;36:*.flac=00;36:*.mid=00;36:*.midi=00;36:*.mka=00;36:*.mp3=00;36:*.mpc=00;36:*.ogg=00;36:*.ra=00;36:*.wav=00;36:*.axa=00;36:*.oga=00;36:*.spx=00;36:*.xspf=00;36:
$_SERVER['WSL_DISTRO_NAME'] => Legacy
$_SERVER['HOSTTYPE'] => x86_64
$_SERVER['PATH'] => /home/linuxbrew/.linuxbrew/bin:/home/linuxbrew/.linuxbrew/sbin:/mnt/c/Users/User/Desktop/cocos2d/cocos2d-x-3.16/templates:/mnt/c/Users/User/Desktop/cocos2d:/mnt/c/Users/User/Desktop/cocos2d/cocos2d-x-3.16/tools/cocos2d-console/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games:/mnt/c/Program Files (x86)/Common Files/Oracle/Java/javapath:/mnt/c/Program Files (x86)/Intel/iCLS Client/:/mnt/c/Program Files/Intel/iCLS Client/:/mnt/c/Windows/system32:/mnt/c/Windows:/mnt/c/Windows/System32/Wbem:/mnt/c/Windows/System32/WindowsPowerShell/v1.0/:/mnt/c/Program Files (x86)/NVIDIA Corporation/PhysX/Common:/mnt/c/Program Files (x86)/Intel/Intel(R) Management Engine Components/DAL:/mnt/c/Program Files/Intel/Intel(R) Management Engine Components/DAL:/mnt/c/Program Files (x86)/Intel/Intel(R) Management Engine Components/IPT:/mnt/c/Program Files/Intel/Intel(R) Management Engine Components/IPT:/mnt/c/php:/mnt/c/ProgramData/ComposerSetup/bin:/mnt/c/WINDOWS/system32:/mnt/c/WINDOWS:/mnt/c/WINDOWS/System32/Wbem:/mnt/c/WINDOWS/System32/WindowsPowerShell/v1.0/:/mnt/c/Program Files (x86)/Yarn/bin/:/mnt/c/WINDOWS/System32/OpenSSH/:/mnt/c/Python27:/mnt/c/Users/User/Desktop/phantomjs/bin:/mnt/c/Program Files (x86)/GtkSharp/2.12/bin:/mnt/c/Program Files/dotnet/:/mnt/c/Program Files/PuTTY/:/mnt/c/Program Files/Git/cmd:/mnt/c/Program Files/nodejs/C:/Program Files/Java/jdk-11.0.1/bin:/mnt/c/Program Files (x86)/Intel/iCLS Client/:/mnt/c/Program Files/Intel/iCLS Client/:/mnt/c/Windows/system32:/mnt/c/Windows:/mnt/c/Windows/System32/Wbem:/mnt/c/Windows/System32/WindowsPowerShell/v1.0/:/mnt/c/Program Files (x86)/NVIDIA Corporation/PhysX/Common:/mnt/c/Program Files (x86)/Intel/Intel(R) Management Engine Components/DAL:/mnt/c/Program Files/Intel/Intel(R) Management Engine Components/DAL:/mnt/c/Program Files (x86)/Intel/Intel(R) Management Engine Components/IPT:/mnt/c/Program Files/Intel/Intel(R) Management Engine Components/IPT:/mnt/c/php:/mnt/c/ProgramData/ComposerSetup/bin:/mnt/c/Program Files (x86)/Yarn/bin/:/mnt/c/Program Files/nodejs/:/mnt/c/Windows/System32/OpenSSH/:/mnt/c/Python27:/mnt/c/Users/User/Desktop/phantomjs/bin:/mnt/c/Program Files (x86)/Microsoft VS Code/bin:/mnt/c/Program Files (x86)/GtkSharp/2.12/bin:/mnt/c/Program Files/dotnet/:/mnt/c/Program Files/PuTTY/:/mnt/c/Program Files/Git/cmd:/mnt/c/Workspace/cocos2d-x-3.16/templates:/mnt/c/Workspace/cocos2d-x-3.16/tools/cocos2d-co:/mnt/c/Users/User/AppData/Local/Android/Sdk/platform-tools:/mnt/c/Users/User/AppData/Local/Microsoft/Wi:/mnt/c/Users/User/AppData/Local/Programs/Microsoft VS Code/bin:/mnt/c/Users/User/AppData/Local/hyper/app-2.0.0/resources/bin:/home/user/.composer/vendor/bin
$_SERVER['PWD'] => /home/linuxbrew/.linuxbrew/etc/php/7.3
$_SERVER['LANG'] => en_CA.UTF-8
$_SERVER['PS1'] => \[\033[38;5;13m\]\u\[\]\[\033[38;5;15m\] \[\]\[\033[38;5;225m\]\w\[\]\[\033[38;5;15m\] \[\]\[\033[38;5;5m\]\$\[\]
$_SERVER['COCOS_X_ROOT'] => /mnt/c/Users/User/Desktop/cocos2d
$_SERVER['SHLVL'] => 1
$_SERVER['HOME'] => /home/user
$_SERVER['HOMEBREW_PREFIX'] => /home/linuxbrew/.linuxbrew
$_SERVER['LOGNAME'] => user
$_SERVER['LESSOPEN'] => | /usr/bin/lesspipe %s
$_SERVER['INFOPATH'] => /home/linuxbrew/.linuxbrew/share/info:
$_SERVER['HOMEBREW_CELLAR'] => /home/linuxbrew/.linuxbrew/Cellar
$_SERVER['LESSCLOSE'] => /usr/bin/lesspipe %s %s
$_SERVER['_'] => /home/linuxbrew/.linuxbrew/bin/php
$_SERVER['OLDPWD'] => /home/linuxbrew/.linuxbrew/etc/php
$_SERVER['PHP_SELF'] =>
$_SERVER['SCRIPT_NAME'] =>
$_SERVER['SCRIPT_FILENAME'] =>
$_SERVER['PATH_TRANSLATED'] =>
$_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] =>
$_SERVER['REQUEST_TIME_FLOAT'] => 1569938889.4979
$_SERVER['REQUEST_TIME'] => 1569938889
$_SERVER['argv'] => Array
(
)

$_SERVER['argc'] => 0
```

Comment: did you check that no other process is listening on 9000 ?  do you have php-fpm ? if yes, that also uses 9000, you should try another port for xdebug. Take a look at my prefs **[here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44371784/phpstorm-xampp-debugging-not-starting/44371963#44371963)**.  Finally, try the actual ip addy of the machine running phpstorm, and make certain that you have enabled 'listening' in phpstorm (the phone icon at the top).

Comment: Yes I have the port 9000 is good with no complaints, I also reconfigured to try other ports, all the same results

Comment: Just to get it out of the way: it's not Xdebug that "hears" connections, quite the opposite - Xdebug makes a connection to the IDE. So, in order to debug, you need to ensure that you can connect **from** WSL **to** the host's port 9000. On my default setup, WSL has direct access to host's ports, so you need no tunnel. Open PhpStorm, make it listen for debug connections, login into WSL and perform `telnet 127.0.0.1 9000`. Would it connect? If so, make PhpStorm stop listening and try again - would it fail? If it would do both, we need to take a look at the Xdebug log.

Comment: First of all, thank you for your reply.  I tested this as you stated and when listening it connect from WSL to 127.0.0.1 9000.  When I stop listening in PhpStorm it fails to connect.  Although the breakpoints still do not work so I am assuming my configuration is still off?

Comment: That's weird. When you run `phpinfo()` by the WSL-based server, what would be the result? Can you share it?
Also, it makes sense to replace the Windows paths with `/c/mnt/xampp/...` so that Xdebug could actually write its logs.

Comment: I posted above as an edit, I deleted some stuff for length let me know if I took out any pertinent information.

Comment: According to what you have after `Zend Engine v3.3.5`, you don't have Xdebug installed. [This](http://prntscr.com/pdyfiz) is what it's supposed to look like.

Comment: Alright thank you, it is very strange because when I ssh in via Phpstorm it detected Xdebug, so I assumed it was correct.  But you're right it is not configured properly.

Comment: The thing is that the remote interpreter in PhpStorm is checking if Xdebug is installed in the CLI mode and not in the web mode. These two modes can have to different .ini files sets.